# TouchableOpacity onPress not working(emulator test)

Tags: reactjs, react-native

So just getting started with `react-native`. I have a stateful component built as below :

```
class LoginView extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
  super(props);
  this.state = {
  inProgress: false
   };
 }

 processLogin(){
  this.setState({
  inProgress: true
  })
 }

render() {
 return (
  <View style={styles.mainContainer}>
    <View style={styles.loginContainer}>
      <TextInput style={styles.input} placeholder="Password" />
      <TouchableOpacity style={styles.button} onPress={() => this.processLogin()}>
        {!this.state.inProgress && <Text style={styles.button_text}>Log in</Text>}/>}
      </TouchableOpacity>
    </View>
  </View>
);}}
```

As you can see, i am binding the `onPress` event of the touchable opacity to the function `processLogin`. But for some reason, the function isn't fired!

The `state` doesn't change, also tried `console.log` but didn't fire either. Made sure that `TouchableOpacity` is imported from `React-Native`.

I am guessing that i messed up the binding. Any leads would be appreciated!

**Note:** Have only been trying this in the emulator, not in a real device yet.

Comment: You have syntax error.

Comment: `<TouchableOpacity
            style={styles.button}
            onPress={() => this.processLogin()}>
            {!this.state.inProgress && (
              <Text style={styles.button_text}>Log in</Text>
            )}
          </TouchableOpacity>` this is ok

Answer (score 0):

instead of using the arrow function on **onPress** prop, use it when you are declaring the business function **processLogin**
So concretly, replace the declaration of this method by :

```
processLogin = () => {
    this.setState({
        inProgress : true
    })
}
```

Then on **onPress** method, just change make it like this :

```
onPress = {this.processLogin}
```

Contrarily, you refer to the wrong **this**
Hope it's gonna help you sir
Regards.

Comment: Doesn't make much of a difference tbh. I rather had a syntax error pointed out in the comments.